# Windows Store (Phone) App 8.1 developement - SSH library

Tags: c#, ssh, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to do a personal project (meaning develop an application) for my Windows Phone 8.1 device which requires sending a very simple SSH command.

None of the libraries that offer SSH functionality and were tried work. They all probably require stuff from System.Net.Sockets package, which isn't available anymore, or they simply can't be added to the project (using NuGet). (For example Tampir.SharpSSH, libssh2 library and Chilkat .NET Class library.)

My question is therefore very simple:

**Is there any .Net SSH library that works with Windows Phone 8.1 apps?**

All my searches have led me nowhere, I'm getting a bit desperate.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Ok, is there any **free** .Net SSH library for Windows Phone 8.1? I just need the simplest of solutions, not even key authentication... Chilkat's library pack is therefore unfortunetely not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Chilkat .NET has the WinRT version library, it should work for Window Phone 8.1.

[Chilkat WinRT Component](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_WinRT.asp)

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks. :) There's just one tiny problem left: as I am pretty new to C# (coming from Java), I have no idea what to do with it. :\

Comment: No matter how I compile this, I always get a 'System.TypeLoadException' when trying to access any classes inside.. I tried searching for this problem in general, but that's pretty useless...

Comment: Or, after following these instructions here: stackoverflow.com/questions/17864054/how-to-package-a-windows-runtime-component-for-distribution I get a 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' with HRESULT: 0x8007007E, even though the project "knows" where to look for the dll, since it wouldn't let me compile when I move it.. This is very frustrating.. I want such a simple thing..

Comment: Made it work with different version of his library, but this isn't a solution. I need to send a single ssh command every now and then and that's not something I'm willing to pay hundreds of dollars worth library package for. I don't need any other of those libraries.